# Как увеличить скорость обработки dnspython

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dns

Как увеличить скорость обработки парсера МХ-записей? у меня есть 1.млн строк и он очень долго их обрабатывает примерно сутки... Что можно с этим сделать?

```
import dns.resolver
from time import time
import time
from service import domains



def init_to_domain() -> None:
    dns.resolver.default_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
    dns.resolver.default_resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']
    print(len(domains), "addresses loaded...starting mx lookup.\n\n")


def check_dns_to_mx():
    mxRecords = []
    emailAddresses = []
    for domain in domains:
        try:
            answers = dns.resolver.resolve(domain.split("@", 1)[1], 'MX')
        except:
            print("some error")
            mxRecord = "some error"
        else:
            mxRecord = answers[0].exchange.to_text()
            print(mxRecord)
        finally:
            mxRecords.append(mxRecord)
            emailAddresses.append(domain)
            print(domain)
            time.sleep(.200)
    return mxRecords and emailAddresses
```

я разбил код на куски, декомпозировал, в конце у меня была запись в файл csv данные

```
filename = 'result.csv'
mxRecords = []
emailAddresses = []
df = pd.DataFrame({"EmailAddress": emailAddresses,
                   "MXRecords": mxRecords})

print("\n", str(len(emailAddresses)), "records processed")
df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: Чтоб оптимизировать нужно выяснить, где узкое место. Используйте https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html чтоб выяснить, где тратится время

Comment: Это сутки с запросами по сети к днс? Или сама обработка результатов.

Comment: тратиться время скорее всего на переменной answer, он заполняет сначало в память, а потом обработанные результаты он записывает в csv через pandas? Сама обработка результатов занимает время много...

Comment: У вас 1кк записей и после каждой записи идет задержка на 200мс, итого `print((1_000_000 * 0.200) / 3600)` = 55 часов задержек :) Но если уменьшить задержку, скрипт будет ДОСить

Comment: `print`, кстати, тоже может много времени отнимать, если их будет несколько миллионов ))

Comment: То есть, получается технический невозможно ускорить скорость работы скрипта, если только как гласит документация 1 запрос в минуту, но на 1кк займет 18 часов работы, а если попробовать поставить на сервер и сделать несколько IP и настроить маршрутизацию?

Comment: @Seavegen Ну да, как-то так и делают, но это уже совершенно другой вопрос вообще-то )